# What is the nature of given language?

Tags: automata, regular-language

$$L=\{a^n b^n :n\geq0, n\neq100 \}$$
I just wanted to know that through pda. How will we make sure that $n\neq100$ or say I put a restriction that $n\geq100$. How to design a PDA using these specifications ?

Comment: IT's always better, absent a 100% clear context, not to use acronyms. Also, how to define a pushdown automata varies from source to source - they are all basically the same, but the way to express it is different. Finally, the title and the question don't match - you seem to be assuming something about the "nature of" $L$.

Comment: Start by defining a pushdown automaton to recognize $\{a^nb^n : n\geq0\}$. Can you do that? It would be helpful if you showed us how you describe a PDA, even if it is not exactly the right one.

Comment: start with 100 finite states automata in parallel and at the end of the $100$th add the PDA recognizing $a (a^n b^n) b^{101}$

Comment: @David , first I will push all the incoming a's onto stack and then on each b , I will pop a from the stack

Comment: @user1952009  I couldn't get what do you mean by 100 finite states automata in parallel ,please clarify it a bit more

Comment: Why do you want to use a pushdown automaton to find "the nature of your language"? If you want to prove that it is context free, there is a much shorter way...

Comment: I was just interested in finding out whether it is a DCFL or CFL ,and how to design PDA for it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PDA for $\mathcal L=\{a^nb^n|a,b\geq0\}$

[image]

---

Instand of $n\neq 100$ I will take $n\neq 3$ and you can do the same for $n\neq 100$

PDA for  $\mathcal L=\{a^nb^n|a,b\geq0,n\neq 3\}:$

[image]

Comment: your q7 state is useless

Comment: @user1952009 did you try to run it? it works, period, q7 is not useless I checked it.

Comment: http://www.paris8.free.fr/pda.png (accepting only if the stack is empty)

Comment: @user1952009 you are wrong your automata accepts $z=aaaaabb\notin \mathcal L$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34558/discussion-between-nehorai-and-user1952009).